# How to allow a modifier only once for multiple elements in Xtext Grammar?

Tags: dsl, xtext

I want to create the following DSL

```
namespace x.y.z
system <NAME> {
    component A { ... }
    component B { ... }
    coordinator component C { ... }
    component D { ... }
}
```

All `component`'s have the same structure except that one and only one requires a `coordinator` modifier.

By now I tried two different grammars:

```
System:
    'system' name=ValidID '{'
        (coordinatorComponent=CoordinatorComponent) & 
        (components+=NonCoordinatorComponent*) & 
        (constraints=ComponentConstraints)?
    '}'
;

ComponentConstraints:
    'constraints' '{}'
;

CoordinatorComponent:
    'coordinator' 'component' {Component}
;

NonCoordinatorComponent:
    'component' {Component};

Component:
    name=ValidID '{'
        features+=Feature*
    '}'
;
```

and the same one with slight changes

```
CoordinatorComponent:
    'coordinator' {Component}
;

NonCoordinatorComponent:
    {Component};

Component:
    'component' name=ValidID '{'
        features+=Feature*
    '}'
;
```

The first one results in an error **rule ruleSystem failed predicate: {getUnorderedGroupHelper().canLeave(grammarAccess.getSystemAccess().getUnorderedGroup())}?** in the editor when writing the DSL (not the grammar).

The second one works but still I think it is weird because it is not really using a *modifier* but a whole new type. Is there a better way to define `Component` in general and using a modifier which MUST be used exactly once within `System`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using parser fragments

```
System:
    'system' name=ValidID '{'
        ((coordinatorComponent=CoordinatorComponent) & 
        (components+=NonCoordinatorComponent*) & 
        (constraints=ComponentConstraints)?)
    '}'
;

ComponentConstraints:
    'constraints' '{}'
;

CoordinatorComponent:
    'coordinator' 'component' Component
;

NonCoordinatorComponent:
    'component' Component;

fragment Component:
    name=ValidID '{'
        features+=Feature*
    '}'
;
```